# attribute barrierMargin (aka com.example.myapp:barrierMargin) not found

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After updating xamarin.forms version to 5.0.2244 facing attribute barrierMargin (aka com.example.myapp:barrierMargin) not found myapp.Android\obj\Debug\100\lp\112\jl
res\layout\material_timepicker_dialog.xml   39 and build failed.

Comment: `barrierMargin` seems an Android attribute. Did you used like the code below `app:barrierMargin=“10dp”`? Have you add the app namespace( `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" `)?

Comment: im not coded this file directly. its generating in  myapp.Android\obj\Debug\100\lp\112\jl
res\layout\material_timepicker_dialog.xml  i've update the xamarin.forms from 4.7 to 5.0

Comment: facing failed linking file resources error as well

Comment: It seems a native file which generate automatically. Does this only occur on the current project or each project? Try to delete the bin and obj folder to clean and rebuild to regenerate again. And when downgrade from 5.0 to 4.7, does this still occur?

Answer (score 1):

We got the same error after updating Xamarin.Forms from version 5.0.0.1931 to 5.0.0.2337:

> material_timepicker_dialog.xml(39): [APT2260] attribute barrierMargin (aka com.example.myapp:barrierMargin) not found.
>
> Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(157, 3): [APT2061] failed linking file resources.

After updating Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout from version 1.1.3.2 to 2.1.1.2 we could not reproduce this error.